# Freebase suggest: how to get results in other language

Tags: jquery, freebase

I need to get a list of cities in french for freebase suggest.
I'm trying something like

```
$(".location_input").suggest({type:'/location/citytown', name: [{ lang: '/lang/fr'}] } );
```

or

```
$(".location_input").suggest({type:'/location/citytown',  lang: '/lang/fr'} );
```

But it doesn't help this way. Any ideas? Documentations is a bit unclear on this matter

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from their API (any many attempts here), this just isn't supported.

The `lang` option *seems* to only be supported on some of their direct mysql methods, but not the `suggest` method the plugin/widget uses.  I could be wrong, and the status on this may change, but at the time of this answer: it's certainly an unintuitive and undocumented option, if it exists.

Comment: it works perfectly with queries. I hope they implemented it for freebase suggest either.

Answer (score 1):

You can now ! try this :

```
.suggest({
  lang : "fr",
  filter:'(all type:/location/citytown)'
});
```

The jquery suggest script has upgraded. You can download it there : https://www.gstatic.com/freebase/suggest/4_0/suggest.min.js

Download the updated css as well while you're at it : https://www.gstatic.com/freebase/suggest/4_0/suggest.min.css

I found those links and more documentation there : http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Freebase_Suggest